# Using requests module in flask route function

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

Consider the following minimal working flask app:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "I am /"

@app.route("/api")
def api():
    return "I am /api"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This happily works. But when I try to make a GET request with the "requests" module from the `hello` route to the `api` route - I never get a response in the browser when trying to access `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

```
from flask import Flask
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api")
    return "I am /" # This never happens :(

@app.route("/api")
def api():
    return "I am /api"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

So my questions are: Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: You actually should just call `api` to get a result. Not use requests on your own application.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer very true in this instance but the usage might occur in a lower layer module like in my case where the function is not invokable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are running your WSGI app with the Flask test server, which by default uses a single thread to handle requests. So when your one request thread tries to call back into the same server, **it is still busy trying to handle that one request**.

You'll need to enable threading:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

or use a more advanced WSGI server; see [Deployment Options](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploying/#deployment).

Comment: I was not aware of this (until now). Thanks!

Comment: From the `Flask.run()` source it looks like `threaded` is a kwargs options that ultimately works its way down to `werkzeug.serving.run_simple()`, which further pushes down to `make_server()` which then `return ThreadedWSGIServer`. Is there a way to trigger this for a Flask app instance apart from its `run` method? I'm trying to utilize this option in the context seen here [flask_embed.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.5dev14/examples/howto/server_embed/flask_embed.py) which nests the Flask app in some tornado objects.

Comment: @jxramos: That code uses a different server to serve the WSGI container (holding the Flask app). Replace that with a threaded server.

Comment: I might be constrained by a Tornado server due to the Bokeh setup I'm trying to support. See the linked question at right. So far it looks like Tornado is by design [single threaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962076/is-concurrency-is-possible-in-tornado). Looks like I'll need to deepen my understanding of Bokeh's dependency on Tornado.