# Python Requests library not working with Flask app own routes

Tags: python, curl, flask, routes, python-requests

On my flask app I've a route (http://localhost:5000/api/users/) which returns user lists from database as JSON format and it works perfectly fine when requesting through curl or google chrome postman.Assume the route is declared as the code below:

```
@app.route('/api/users/')
def users():
    return 'Some json results...'
```

However some point on my app I've another route where I need to use the same user lists, so I decided to submit a get request and pull the users from '/api/users/' route. I've installed python requests library and here is the route definition below which should return the same user lists:

```
@app.route('/api/someroute/')
def someroute():
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/api/users/')
    return r.json()
```

Now submitting a get request to this route ('/api/someroute/') through postman or curl keep loading forever until I shut down the app. It returns nothing, no error and also freeze all other routes. Like while request is still loading for 'someroute' if I try to request data from users route ('/api/users/') keeps loading also. But when I try to request data from some external url it works fine. Here is the customized code requesting data form external resource:

```
@app.route('/api/someroute/')
def someroute():
    r = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    return r.json()
```

Submitting get request to someroute now works fine and return data as expected

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

I tried many external urls and each of them passed without any issue it just stop working when submitting request to it's own routes/urls.

This scenario is only for sake of understanding, I need to achieve something more complex and that's why I must have to submit request to app own routes.Have no idea what is going wrong, stuck on it for so long. Any help is very much appreciated.

Update: Enabled threading and it start working fine requesting to close this question.
Solved By: [Using requests module in flask route function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878689/using-requests-module-in-flask-route-function?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened because your flask server has one thread. When you do request, thread processes you request and can't process another request which it does during processing.

Try to run another process with different port and change your url and it would work. Also, you can run your server with `--with-threads` option.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You're absolutely right enabling multi threading makes everything ok.

Comment: sorry accidentally clicked on it. Marked as correct solution again :) Thank you