# Key Error when unpacking JSON in flask python

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to make an API call through flask in python and i created a function to unpack the dictionary. This function runs fine outside the flask code but when I try to route the function, I get a key error. This snippet here works fine separately:

```
response = requests.get(url=end_point, params=parameters, headers=resp_header)
#Change json into dict then to pandas dataframe
gym_dict = response.json()
gym_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Picture','Name','Location','Rating','Phone#'))
for valg in gym_dict['businesses']:
   'some random function'
```

This would properly unpack and append to dataframe. However when I put it in a flask route like:

```
@app.route("/",methods=["POST", "GET"])
def zipsub():
'some random params'
    response = requests.get(url=end_point, params=parameters, headers=resp_header)
    #Change json into dict then to pandas dataframe
    gym_dict = response.json()
    gym_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Picture','Name','Location','Rating','Phone#'))
    for valg in gym_dict['businesses']:
       'some random function'
```

A key error for gym_dict['businesses'] pops up. Has anyone else experienced this and know what the difference is and why? Thank you.

..

Comment: does `gym_dict` has `businesses` key ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752194/python-requests-library-not-working-with-flask-app-own-routes

Comment: well in the first script it is. After I tried using in a flask route, the key error comes up

Answer (score 0):

This may occur if the response from the request is not 200, and it is returning some error.

So if an error is returned, it will not contain the key 'businesses'.

Comment: Hello, thank for the reply. It seems the response for the request was working fine. I figured that the error is not in the loop but in the API call earlier on in the script, or lack of. I opened a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69195697/flask-route-is-not-calling-yelp-api-on-python.