# Flask route is not calling Yelp API on Python

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I made this route on my index page that takes the POST from a HTML form and inputs the variable in the API call. I thought the initial problem with the for loop to iterate through the dictionary, but it seems that the API isn't even being called, according to the API Usage on yelp. Does anyone have an idea why this route is not working properly? Thanks

```
@app.route("/",methods=["POST", "GET"])
def zipsub():
    global gym_df
    if request.method == "POST" and 'zipsearch' in request.form:
        zip_code = request.form.get['zipsearch']
        #Client ID
        clientid = 'client_id'
        #define api key, endpoint and header for request to yelp API
        api_key = 'api_key'
        end_point = 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search'
        resp_header = {'Authorization': 'bearer {}'.format(api_key)}
        
        #define parameters
        parameters = {'term':'gym',
                        'limit':5,
                        'radius':3200,
                        'location':'{}'.format(zip_code),
                        }
        #make api call
        response = reqs.get(url=end_point, params=parameters, headers=resp_header)

        #Change json into dict then to pandas dataframe
        gym_dict = response.json()

        for valg in gym_dict['businesses']:
            if valg in gym_dict['businesses']:
                #only display street address
                valg['location']['display_address'] = valg['location']['display_address'][0]
                data = valg['image_url'],valg['name'],valg['location']['display_address'],valg['rating'],valg['phone']
                datalist = list(data)
                seriesly = pd.Series(datalist, index = gym_df.columns)
                gym_df = gym_df.append(seriesly, ignore_index=True)
                #ORDER DATAFRAME BY RATING
                gym_df = gym_df.sort_values(by=['Rating'], ascending=False)
                #gym_df.to_html(headers='True', table_id='my_table')
                gym_df.to_sql("gym_df", engine, if_exists='append')

    return render_template('table.html', tables=gym_df.to_html(table_id='my_table'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this:

```
def zipsub():
    global gym_df
    if request.method == "POST":
        zip_code = request.form.get('zipsearch')
        #Client ID
```

and

```
return render_template('table.html', column_names=gym_df.columns.values, row_data=list(gym_df.values.tolist()), zip=zip)
```

This fix let me properly call and unpack the API results.